# Django project cannot be accessed using IPV6 address

Tags: django, ubuntu, ipv6

I am running my Django project on a ubuntu server. I have changed the allowed host in settings.py

> ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my_IPV4', 'my_IPV6', 'localhost']

I allowed access to port 8000 by `sudo ufw allow 8000`.

I run the server by `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` however I can only access the IPV4 address but the IPV6 address on port 8000 is not reachable. My IPV6 address is active but port 8000 seems not working. Did I miss something on configuring
IPV6?

Comment: The `0.0.0.0/0` address is only for IPv4. The IPv6 equivalent is `::/0`.

Comment: @RonMaupin Hi, should I run ```python manage.py runserver [::]:8000``` and access by ```http://[my_IPV6]:8000``` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know. I do know that listening on `0.0.0.0/0` only listens for IPv4. Some things listening on `::/0` will listen for bot IPv4 and IPv6, but I cannot answer about your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the documentation about IPV6 and got some answers, you must put IPV6 in square brackets.

Localhost for IPV6: `::1`

Any address for IPV6 :   `::`   (for IPV4 is `0.0.0.0`)

So in settings.py AllOWED_HOSTS should be `['my_IPV4', '[my_IPV6]', 'localhost']`

Django run server command:  `python manage.py runserver [::]:8000`

To access the IPV6 address with port using `https://[IPV6 address]:8000`

You will need brackets for URL to access IPV6 address even without port number

`http://[fe80::b746:6473:e65f:5dd4]/foo/bar`

`http://[fe80::b746:6473:e65f:5dd4]:8000/foo/bar`

Reference https://cheat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ipv6.html

Comment: Correct. Yes it works. I think the question should be How to access Django project using IPV6 address.

Answer (score 1):

The argument `--ipv6, -6` uses IPv6 for the development server. This changes the default IP address from 127.0.0.1 to ::1.

Run Port 8000 on the IPv6 address of the host localhost:

```
django-admin runserver -6 localhost:8000
```

Reference:
[Django Docs: Examples of using different ports and addresses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/django-admin/#examples-of-using-different-ports-and-addresses)